# How can I downgrade GCC 7.5 to 7.4 ? (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, nvidia

I bought a Dell PowerEdge T430, which has no graphics cards, and installed an old Nvidia 6200 TurboCache card on it.
It is recognized in the `lspci | grep VGA` command, but the drivers are not intalled.

I did download them, login in the runlevel 3 (`telinit 3`), and run the install script.
Just before the installation starts, the script tells me the following:
`CC Version check failed, the gcc version used to compile the kernel (7.4) is not the same as the current gcc version (7.5)`
When I run `gcc --version` it turns out I have the 7.5 version installed.

I ran across Internet and could not find a way to downgrade my GCC version.

How can I to go GCC version 7.4 for the sake of this driver install ?

Answer (score -1):

Easiest is maybe build from sources:

- Get GCC sources, [download](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) and unpack or via [git](https://gcc.gnu.org/git.html) somewhere to `srcdir` in HOME or so.
- Get the prerequisites:

  ```
  cd $srcdir
  ./contrib/download_prerequisites
  ```
- Make a build directory `builddir` somewhere **outside** of `srcdir`.
- Configure GCC in `builddir`:

  ```
  cd $builddir
  $srcdir/configure --prefix=$installdir --disable-bootstrap --disable-nls
  ```

  - You can install it in `installdir` somewhere in your HOME or wherever.  In general you do not want to replace the system GCC.
  - If you prefer a real bootstrap (3-stage build) then ditch `--disable-bootstrap`
  - If you only need some languages, then `--enable-languages=c,c++` etc.
  - If you prefer funny diagnostics in native language, ditch `--disable-nls`.
- Make GCC:

  ```
  cd $builddir
  make
  ```
- Install GCC:

  ```
  cd $builddir
  make install
  ```

Now you have a `gcc` and `gcc-7.4` something in `$(installdir)/bin/`

At your option,

- You can soft-link `$HOME/bin/gcc` to `$(installdir)/bin/gcc`, similar for `g++` and the other compilers if you need them. `$HOME/bin` must be prior to system paths.
- Something like `export PATH="$(installdir)/bin:$PATH"` in the shell where you want to use it in favor of system gcc.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I thought about it but your explanation made it very clear, cheers :)